# How to correctly clear a Map in java

Tags: java, hashmap, jackson

I am trying create a java object from a Map and then convert the object to an XML String. At the end I will send the XML with a post request. after each successful request I have to clear the data so that only the new data will be posted.

```
 private void send(){
    try {
      Map<String, List<Object>> data = getData();

      Message dataMessage = Message
          .serialize(data);

      XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
      String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(dataMessage);
      Log.i("debug", "xml " + xml);
      getData().clear();     //Clearing the data hier is problematic
    }catch(Exception e){
      Log.e("debug", "Error! " + e);
    }
  }
```

If I do not clear the data the xml message is logged correctly but the old data are also printed as expected. If I comment the line and clear the data at the end of the send function no messages are printed. I do not understand what the problem is. Could it be that the parsing of the xml is happening asynchronous and the data is deleted before the parsing happens? Do you have any solution?

Comment: You are *clearing* what `getData()` returns and not the `data` map itself.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html there is a  .clear() method. See the oracle docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{name of hash map}.clear()
```

method to clean the hash map

Refer [here for more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)